# Can't get the value of input method val()

Tags: jquery

Have a DIV which contains input's:

[image]

Here is the layout:

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group afc" id="datepicker-common-table">
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" placeholder="Начальная дата">
   <span class="input-group-addon"> - </span>
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" placeholder="Конечная дата">
</div>
```

Here is the script which tries to get the values after they are installed:

```
$(document).on('change', "input[name='start']", function()
{       
   $(document).on('change', "input[name='end']", function()
   {
      var startVal = $("#datepicker-common-table > input:text").val();
      var endVal = $("#datepicker-common-table > input:text").val();
      console.log( startVal + " - " + endVal );
   });
});
```

As a result, in the console get the following output:

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up. Each time your `input[name=start]` changes, you are binding another change event to `input[name=end]`. You should probably unbind the trigger before attaching it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your screenshots, you need to use the `changeDate` event along with the data it provides:

```
$("input[name='start']").datepicker({

}).on("changeDate", function(e) {
    var selectedDate = e.date; // Get the date value from the event
    console.log("Date Changed", e.date);
});
```

Therefore, for your use-case (you only want to log the date when **both** are picked):

```
var dates = { start: null, end: null };
$(".input-sm").datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    language: "en",
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoClose: true
}).on("changeDate", function(e) {
    dates[this.name] = e.date;
    if(dates.start && dates.end) {
        console.log("Both dates selected");   
        console.log(dates.start);
        console.log(dates.end);
    }
});
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/eFkLt/)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
$(document).on('change', "input[name='start'],input[name='end']", function() {
    var startVal = $("#datepicker-common-table > input[name='start']").val();
    var endVal = $("#datepicker-common-table > input[name='end']").val();
    console.log( startVal + " - " + endVal );
});
```

---

Since you're using Bootstrap datepicker based on your comment, you need to use event **[changeDate()](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/events.html#changedate)** to keep track of when the date is changed:

```
$("input[name='start'],input[name='end']").on('changeDate', function() {
    var startVal = $("#datepicker-common-table > input[name='start']").val();
    var endVal = $("#datepicker-common-table > input[name='end']").val();
    console.log( startVal + " - " + endVal );
});
```

Comment: @Artem Does your datepicker definitely fire the `change` event?

Comment: @Artem You need to use the `changeDate` event: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/events.html

Comment: @RGraham  please help, for example

Comment: @Felix I checked your update, but still empty. http://joxi.ru/Hx5WUxjKTJAjfxRdSfs
http://joxi.ru/Vh5WU_3JTJDeV4TkFg0

Comment: @Felix I found something, look this http://joxi.ru/WDBWUxjKTJCQDjZP6XU and this http://joxi.ru/mTBWUxjKTJDKfenHIZM now how to get this date

Answer (score 2):

here is what you require, you need to use `keyup` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker-common-table input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function(){



var startVal = $('#datepicker-common-table input[name="start"]').val();
var endVal = $('#datepicker-common-table input[name="end"]').val();

    alert(startVal);

        })
    });
```

[Here is **Fiddle DEMO using Jquery 1.10.1**](http://jsfiddle.net/N77kb/1/)

Comment: He needs to get these values, as they change (i.e. in real time); This static assignment will not help him.

Comment: i added fiddle demo, its working check if script url is not right or you are doing some other thing wrong

Comment: i have attached demo fiddle there its working means its something other wrong in your page]

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad  Yes you have, but I have to page does not work, Therefore, and asked for help :(

Comment: what i am trying to tell you the script is fine you need to check some other problem is there js code is fine

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad I agree with you completely, I pressed the up arrow on your answer!

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad not resolved, but I found something, look this http://joxi.ru/WDBWUxjKTJCQDjZP6XU and this http://joxi.ru/mTBWUxjKTJDKfenHIZM now how to get this date

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the callback provided is asynchronous and you cannot guarantee that you will have immediate access to the values. You can push the value into a queue, and poll it if you know the minimum length required in order to complete your task you could poll.

This will poll the object every second looking for not null values on the to properties, once it finds them, it stops, so if you need to be continuously watching, then it will take some adjustment.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ6k3/18/)

```
var inputValues = {
    start: '',
    end: ''
}
$(document).on('keyup', function() {      
    var start = $(document).find("input[name='start']").val();
    var end = $(document).find("input[name='end']").val();
    inputValues.start = start;
    inputValues.end = end;
});
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function() {
    var fullString;
    if(inputValues.start != '' && inputValues.end != '') {
        console.log("Start: " + inputValues.start + " End: " + inputValues.end);
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why not just check `NAMES` on each `change` if you're only pushing on an event?

Comment: @RGraham I rewrote it completely, let me know what you think on this udpated version.

Comment: @RGraham I found something, look this http://joxi.ru/WDBWUxjKTJCQDjZP6XU and this http://joxi.ru/mTBWUxjKTJDKfenHIZM now how to get this date